# ionic cordova resources no se instala global

Tags: ionic, npm, cordova

He encontrado fallos en la instalación me dice que no puedo instalar Ionic Cordova resources por falta de permisos, a pesar de que estoy como administrador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que me ayudo fue instalar local en el proyecto y ejecutar el Ionic resources
los comandos fueron:

> npm i cordova-res@latest --save
>
> ionic cordova resources ios --force